# Can't access EntitlementService Webservice on wso2is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to access the EntitlementService running on a WSO2 IdentityServer on localhost.
I want to evaluate IS for use as XACML engine. This is all just Proof-Of-Concept code and tests.

I tried both with a Java client and a php client.

The java code which can be downloaded here:
https://sites.google.com/site/securedecentralizedblog/is/EntitlementClient.java?attredirects=0&d=1

I only changed the directory for the wso2is related stuff. Running it gives me these error in the wso2is console:

```
[2014-05-05 01:36:00,058] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  Authentication Failed : Invalid remote address passed - https://localhost:9443/
[2014-05-05 01:36:29,127]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil} -  Could not find IP address for domain name : https://localhost:9443/
```

Which seems really weird as localhost normally always resolves...

Also tried with a hand made php script:

```
<?php
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
));

$auth = array(
        'trace' => true,
        'login'=>'admin',
        'password'=>'admin',
        'stream_context'=>$context
        );

$login_client = new SoapClient('https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl',$auth);
$client = new SoapClient('https://localhost:9443/services/EntitlementService?wsdl',$auth);


$request = file_get_contents('../xacml_get_users.xml');


echo "\n\nGoing to start login call...\n\n";
try {
  $login_response = $login_client->login($auth);
  $response_headers = $login_client-> __getLastResponseHeaders();
  $request_cookie = $login_client->_cookies;
  $a_jsessionid = $request_cookie['JSESSIONID'];
  $jsessionid = $a_jsessionid[0];
  $cutstr = substr($response_headers,strpos($response_headers,'Set-Cookie: '));
  $cookie = substr($cutstr,strlen('Set-Cookie: '));
  $cookie = substr($cookie, 0, strpos($cookie,';'));

  echo "\n\nGoing to start decision call...\n\n";

  $cookie_name="JSESSIONID";
  $cookie_value=$jsessionid;
  $client->__setCookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);
  $client->getDecision($request);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I get past the login call, but then after the "start decision call" I get this error message in the client:

```
Error occurred while evaluating XACML request
```

And in the wso2is console:

```
[2014-05-05 01:33:03,733] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.EntitlementService} -  Error occurred while evaluating XACML request
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.cache.IdentityCacheKey.hashCode(IdentityCacheKey.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1016)
    at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl.containsKey(CacheImpl.java:260)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.cache.EntitlementBaseCache.getValueFromCache(EntitlementBaseCache.java:144)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.cache.DecisionCache.getFromCache(DecisionCache.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pdp.EntitlementEngine.getFromCache(EntitlementEngine.java:384)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pdp.EntitlementEngine.evaluate(EntitlementEngine.java:229)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.EntitlementService.getDecision(EntitlementService.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

What could be going wrong? I need this to work otherwise we won't be able to choose wso2is for our project.

Also, is there any REST API for this planned?
If yes, for when?

Comment: We actually need the php version most importantly :)

Comment: Als using the client code from https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/sample/atm/client/ produces the same error about IdentityCacheKey...

Comment: Evaluating the same Policy Evaluation Request I use through SOAP with the "TryIt" page of the wso2is admin console works fine. It's only when accessing by webservice that it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally seem to have solved it.
I used the other available WSDL function, getDecisionByAttributes.

It still generates some weird exception in the wso2 IS server, but I actually get the return
value "Permit" or "Deny" (or "Indeterminate").

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
));

$http_auth = array(
        'trace' => true,
        'login'=>'admin',
        'password'=>'admin',
        'stream_context'=>$context
        );

$client = new SoapClient('https://localhost:9443/services/EntitlementService?wsdl',$http_auth);

try {
  $res = $client->getDecisionByAttributes(array("subject"=>"okuser","resource"=>"https://api.example.org/api/v1/users","action"=>"GET"));
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($res->return);
  $decision = $xml->Result->Decision;;
  echo $decision;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TryIt` also using the web service method... It means, when you are sending the request from web service API, it also must work..  According to the `null pointer`,  it seems to be that XACML request is not coming in your SOAP message.  I suppose to tract the message that is going from your PHP client...  Also the for debug purpose,  you can enable the [debug](http://soasecurity.org/2014/02/26/how-to-wso2is-troubleshooting-wso2-identity-server-1/) logs in WSO2IS,  which helps you to see XACML request/response messages.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script, try replacing the line

```
$client->getDecision($request);
```

by:

```
$client->getDecision(["request" => $request]);
```

This should take care of your NullPointerException.

This is because according the WSDL, the SOAP method getDecision need a *named* parameter called "request", containing the actual XACML request:

```
<xs:element name="getDecision">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="request" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```